# Do not show child pages until parent page has loaded in accordion menu

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion menu on the LHS of various pages on my site

```
http://94.76.203.52
```

Click on Senior, Junior etc at the top.

I have content on the parent sections, but I would only like the sub menus to appear after the parent link has been clicked, because as you might have seen, the sub menus appear before the page loads.

I am using this plugin with Worpdress

http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-plugin-jquery-vertical-accordion-menu-widget/

Here is the CSS that I have for the Senior LHS menu:

```
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item {border-top: 0px solid #00365E; text-align:right; font-size:11px; margin-left:25px;}
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul, #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul li {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; list-style: none;}
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul a {background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position:10px center; border-top: 1px solid #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; padding: 5px 5px 5px 32px; text-decoration:none; display: block; font-weight: bold; text-transform:lowercase;color:#ECF6F5; background-color:#00365E;}
 *#dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul a.dcjq-parent {background-color:#00365E; color:#ECF6F5;}
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul a.dcjq-parent.active { background-color: #00365E; color:#84CAC6; }
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul li ul li.current-menu-item a {background-color: #ECF6F5; color:#84CAC6; }
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul li ul li.current-menu-item a.active {background-color:      #ECF6F5; color:#00365E; }
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul li ul li.current-menu-item a:hover {background-color:   #ECF6F5; color:#00365E; }
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul li ul li {background-color: #84CAC6; color:white;}
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul li ul li a {background-color: #84CAC6; color:white;}
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul a:hover {background-color:#84CAC6 ; color:#00365E;}
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul li ul li a.dcjq-parent {background-color: #84CAC6; color:white;}
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul li ul li a.dcjq-parent:hover {background-color:#84CAC6 ; color:#00365E;}
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul li ul li a.dcjq-parent.active {background-color: #84CAC6; color:#00365E; }
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul li ul li ul li a {background-color: #ECF6F5; color:#84CAC6; }
 #dc_jqaccordion_widget-7-item ul li ul li ul li a.active {background-color: #ECF6F5; color:#00365E; }
```

Please please can someone help?

Thank you
Marc Hawes

Answer (score 0):

Please give more details - It's hard to know what you're seeing when I can't re-create it. Otherwise, you can hide the 'sidebar' until the document loads...something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.sidebar').show();
});
```

...of course you'll have to hide the sidebar initially (`.sidebar {display:none;}`). Let me know if I'm way off base, but if load order is a problem this would fix it.